# Removing nested keys in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
data = {'a1': {'version': '1',
               'results': {'key':'value'}
              },
        'a2': {'version': '1', 
               'results': {'key':'value'}
              }
       }
```

I need to get rid of the key 'version' and have the output like this:

```
{'a1': {'results': {'key':'value'}},
 'a2': {'results': {'key':'value'}},
...
```

I got the code:

```
data2 = {}
for k, v in data:
    if k == 'version':
    data2[k] = None
```

However, this returns an empty dictionary.

What would be a proper code to achieve this?

Comment: That code isn't indented properly and is a long way from being relevant to the problem. SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {'a1': {'version': '1',
               'results': {'key':'value'}
              },
        'a2': {'version': '1', 
               'results': {'key':'value'}
              }
       }

for inner_dict_key in data:
    if 'version' in  data[inner_dict_key]:
        del data[inner_dict_key]['version']
```

Result:

```
{'a1': {'results': {'key': 'value'}}, 'a2': {'results': {'key': 'value'}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3:

`data2 = {k: {'results': v['results']} for k, v in data.items()}`

Python 2:

replace `items` with `iteritems`

Explanation:

`.items()` gives us an iterator over (key, value) pairs

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a nested dict comprehension

```
data2 = {k: {k: v for k, v in v.items() if k != 'version'} for k, v in data.items()}
```

If you are confused by the scope of the k's and v's you can label the ones from the inner dict

```
data2 = {k: {k1: v1 for k1, v1 in v.items() if k1 != 'version'} for k, v in data.items()}
```

Making new dicts from comprehensions prevents accidental side-effects to `dict` as seen in the answers using `del`

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
data2 = data.copy()
for k in data:
   if 'version' in data[k]:
       del data2[k]['version']
print(data2)
```

Comment: I assume you did the copy to preserve the value of `data`. But because you've modified the nested dicts, you've changed `data` too.